# NSNumber vs Int

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, plist, nsnumber

If integers cannot be written to a dictionary and then to a .plist, but NSNumbers can is it better to use NSNumbers throughout the app, rather than needing to convert every-time saving or loading a dictionary from a .plist?

Comment: Note that memory allocation is expensive. You might want to make your own class similar to NSNumber that would be mutable.

Comment: Prefer `NSInteger` over `int`. This is more portable among various versions Of OS X.

Comment: You can's simply substitute an `NSNumber` (an object) for an `int` (a "scalar value").  It would be incredibly awkward to keep every numerical quantity in an `NSNumber` and convert from/to for every computation.  Using `NSInteger` instead of `int`, on the other hand, is a reasonable thing to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a generalization: Just stick with POD types until you *need* to use an object based representation, such as `NSNumber`. The performance is much better with the PODs, but you'll need `NSNumber` in some cases.

In some cases, it may make sense to use `NSNumber` instead -- this is typically when you *reuse* a `NSNumber` often -- this is to avoid making a ton of duplicate `NSNumber`s. Such occurrences are practical only rarely beyond serialization and generic objc interfaces (bindings, transformers, dictionaries).

---

*Update/Details:* The ObjC runtime will in some cases, on some architectures, and on some OS versions substitute a **tagged pointer** representing `NSNumber`s of specific type and domain. Although the internal representation has changed since originally written a few years back, here is a good introduction to the subject: http://objectivistc.tumblr.com/post/7872364181/tagged-pointers-and-fast-pathed-cfnumber-integers-in. Where this can be used, it saves you from slow operations like allocations, locking, and ref count ops. Nevertheless, tagged pointers are incapable of representing every number and it introduces overhead, so you should still favor basic builtins over `NSNumber` as a default. Tagged pointers are a great optimization where applicable, but are far from competing with the builtins when you just need a *number*.

Comment: The great thing is that KVC supports autoboxing, i.e. conversion between scalar types and NSNumber, so there's little need to use NSNumber in properties.

Comment: You might want to revise this considering the implications of 64-bit devices.

Answer (score 0):

NSNumber is object  inherited from NSValue wrapper object.

int is not object.

if use NSNumber u can get more and more function to utilize with them.

http://developer..com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html

NSNumber is a class that helps you to store numeric types as object. It has methods to convert between different types and methods to retrieve a string representation of your numeric value.
If you use a variable day of type NSNumber* the way you did in your example, you are not modifying the value of day but its memory address.

Comment: Your url is missing an apple in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your need. But, if the API requires you to use *int*,  you should use *int*. It it asks you to use *NSNumber* you should use *NSNumber*.

For example, if you are using a *UISegmentedControl*, and you want to select a segment, then,

```
[segmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:aIntVar]; // Can not use NSNumber here
// or
[segmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:[aNumber intValue]];
```